# kali linux boot error

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, lvm

I decided to update my [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/), after which it restarted for the update.
5 minutes in, electricity went out. Later on i powered it on only to give me an error:

```
lib/systemd/stem-generetors/lvm-2activation generator failed with exit status 1
```

and can therefore not start successfully, any tricks would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the following bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=917164 and try to boot with previous kernel version from grub menu. It seems a bug.